# Recognised Op Amp Circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function

I've had a bunch of op amp circuits do research and find the transfer function of,  and this is the last one, does anyone recognise it? I've had a Sallen Key and an All Pass before, and wondering if this is a 'known' setup also:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0apAt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Looking at it I believe at low frquencies the LP filter on the non inverting terminal puts both to \$V_{in}\$ and the divider on the output gives an amplification of ~100. I believe it blocks any high frequencies.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R3 and C1 form a single-pole low pass filter with the -3dB point at 723.432 Hz.
The op-amp that follows is a buffer for and after the filter, with a gain of 100. If the op-amp has +/- 15 volt supplies then Vin is limited to +/- 120 mV or less, or else the op-amp will start clipping the output in the pass band.

It is too simple of a filter to attach any names to it other than a single-pole LPF. Names like Sallen-Key and Bessel and Butterworth are for much more complex designs with at least 2 poles. They often make use of feedback to increase either Q or dampening of the roll-off point.

Comment: I am a bit surprised to read Sallen-Key and Butterworth and Bessel in one enumeration. To me, Sallen-Key is a topology and Butterworth/Bessel are lowpass approximations...